# React's unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, import

I'm still learning React. I'm using WebStorm, and I'm encountering an issue when running it:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Daniel\jettbrains html journey\react tuts\index.js"
C:\Users\Daniel\jettbrains html journey\react tuts\index.js:1
import React from "react";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47in] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)        

Node.js v18.18.0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


const navbar = (
    <div className="meowskie">
        <h1>welcome to react</h1>

    </div>

)

ReactDOM.render(
    navbar, document.getElementById("root-el")
)
```

I tried asking in ChatGPT, and they suggested replacing the `.js` with `.mjs`, but I still encounter a problem that says 'unexpected token'.

Comment: How did you setup the project? share what template you are using for setup.